# Stored procedure doesn't find Linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a problem with Procedure and Linked server. (Simple scheme is showed in image) [image]

And I have select which **works just fine** (it selects all students that are from city 'Kaunas'):

```
 SELECT * FROM myserver.dbo.student
  WHERE student.cityid =
 (SELECT [id] FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[city]
  WHERE [name]='Kaunas')
```

Now I tried to make a stored procedure which can take city as parameters and select students that are from city.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE StudentByCity
    -- parameters
    @CityName varchar = 'Kaunas'
AS
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT * FROM myserver.dbo.student
        WHERE student.cityid =
           (SELECT [id] FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[city]
           WHERE [name]=@CityName)
END
GO
```

However execing procedure returns me empty select.

Comment: The format is [Linkedserver].[Database].[dbo].[city]

Comment: It is formatted, right. I just mistyped in StackOverflow. Will fix it.

Comment: An empty result means there is no matching data, *not* that the query can't find the server. If it couldn't, you'd get an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@CityName varchar = 'Kaunas'
```

Are you missing the parameter @CityName varchar size? Try

```
@CityName varchar(25) = 'Kaunas'
```